# TypeScript: how to type to http params?

Tags: typescript

I have two query params from the url and trying to take them out by using `{}` and assign types to them. However, it is causing error.

```
const {firstName: string, lastName: string} = req.query;
```

I am getting `cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'string'.`. Is it possible to assign type inside the `{}`? Or, do I have to assign them one by one?

Comment: It's a syntax error. You are trying to assign a value to a type. `const variableName: {firstName: string, lastName: string} = req.query;` Or, if you are trying to destructure the object, the posted answer from tkausl is applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't type your variables *inside* your destructuring assignment as the `:` has a different meaning in objects, you have to type the whole object:

```
const {firstName, lastName}: {firstName: string, lastName: string} = req.query;
```